# Can someone explain me how the code is working and what is the time complexity?

Tags: data-structures

Can someone explain me how the code is working and what is the time complexity ?

```
def foo(n):
    r = 0
    for i in range(1, n):
        for j in range(i, n):
            for k in range(1, j):
                r += 2
                print(r)
                
x = int(input("Enter a number : "))
foo(x)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's trivial to see that r is increased at most $n^3$ times. It's slightly less trivial to see that for i = 1 to n/2 the loop for j iterates at least n/2 times, and for n/4 of those iterations k iterates at least n/4 times, which means at least $n^3 / 16$ operations.